# Excel Add On: Range to String Error; VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, vsto, add-in

I trying to test the value of a range for the string TRUE or string FALSE and am receiving errors on execute.

```
Str = XL.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngSOW,x,12)

If str = "TRUE" Then bSTD = True
```

Any advice?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I am getting the following Errors `System.InvalidCastException occurred
   HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581.aspx. `Return Value Variant`. Fun

Comment: You get a Range back. I have no idea if it's single cell range or not. Maybe 
 try `XL.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngSOW,x,12).Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: Still coming back with same error on that. Tried `....Cells(x,12)` also tried `.Cells(8.12)`. I would think that with a Variant return I could easily check the cell value directly `If XL.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngSOW,x,12) = "TRUE"` yet that does not work either? Thoughts?

Comment: @djv it is a single cell range that I am referencing.

Comment: Ok check out the link to MSDN on this function. The return value varies depending on what is passed to it. We don't know what `rngSOW` or `x` are so it's hard to say what could be wrong. Can you tell us which "version" of the function you are using at least according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581.aspx

Comment: @djv thanks, your last comment did the trick, got me to think a little differently. I came up with the following that did the trick...                        `rng = XL.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngSOW,x,12)`
`xrng = CType(rng, Excel.Range)`
 `val = xRng.Value()`
 `If val = "True" Then bSTD = True`